# Error with object Date() when creating new date

Tags: angular

I'm developing new Angular project that contains information about movies.
There is an in my movie.service.ts when creating new different date.

Here's my error

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'year' of undefined
    at new MovieService (movie.service.ts:17)
    at core.js:1461
    at _callFactory (core.js:8223)
    at _createProviderInstance (core.js:8181)
    at resolveNgModuleDep (core.js:8156)
    at NgModuleRef_.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.NgModuleRef_.get (core.js:8849)
    at resolveDep (core.js:9214)
    at createClass (core.js:9086)
    at createDirectiveInstance (core.js:8971)
    at createViewNodes (core.js:10191)
```

I want to show recent movies in theatres from the last months.
Here's my src code

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Jsonp } from "@angular/http";
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";

import {map} from 'rxjs/operators';
import { getLocaleDayNames } from '../../node_modules/@angular/common';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MovieService {
  date = new Date();
  today = {
    day: this.date.getDate(),
    month: this.date.getMonth(),
    year: this.date.getFullYear(),
    now: `${this.today.year}-${this.today.month}-${this.today.day}`,
    then: `${this.today.year}-${this.today.month - 1}-${this.today.day}`
  };


  apiKey: string = '9e2ecb8b71753c6759e1c9f2cb4f961a';

  constructor(private __jsonp: Jsonp) {
    console.log(`${this.today.now} and ${this.today.then}`);
  }

  getPopular(){
    this.__jsonp.get('https://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?callback=JSONP_CALLBACK&sort_by=popularity.desc')
      .pipe(map(res => res.json()));  
  }

  getInTheatres(){
    this.__jsonp.get('https://api.themoviedb.org/3//discover/movie?primary_release_date.gte=2014-09-15&primary_release_date.lte=2014-10-22')
  }
}
```

Comment: You're calling `this.today.year` before `this.today` has been initialised. You'd have to use `this.date.getFullYear()` (and similar for the `month` and `day`)

Comment: I got it. Then what should I do? assign it to the brand new variable?

Comment: Not quite sure what you're suggesting... I'm saying you need something like ` now: `${this.date.getFullYear()}-${this.date.getMonth()}-${this.date.getDate()}`,`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to initialize variables before you even create them. The simplest way that you can achieve it, is just do it inside the constructor. something like that:

```
  today;
  constructor() {
    const date = new Date();
    const dmy = {
      day: date.getDate(),
      month: date.getMonth(),
      year: date.getFullYear(),
    }
    this.today = {
      day: `${dmy.day}`,
      month: `${dmy.month}`,
      year: `${dmy.year}`,
      now: `${dmy.year}-${dmy.month}-${dmy.day}`,
      then: `${dmy.year}-${dmy.month - 1}-${dmy.day}`
    };
    console.log(this.today)
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Take three local variables for day, month and year and then use them in today object it’ll work perfectly.